# Heroku installing Amazon RDS : mysql or mysql2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-ec2, mysql2

I'm installed the Amazon RDS Add-on in Heroku, and created OK an instance in Amazon AWS. But I can't run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

It's ending with

```
(...)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-    3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:38:in    `select_values'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `get_all_versions'
```

When I created my instance I followed the instructions from Heroku :

```
$ heroku addons:add amazon_rds url=mysql2://user:pass@rdshostname.amazonaws.com/databasename
```

And since then, I'm fighting with Mysql2. First I noticed in Heroku that it was pointing to

```
mysql://user:pass@mydatabase.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/MyFirstDb
```

Is it normal that there is no 2 like mysql2://user ? I added it. I changed my Gemfile with

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3.7'
```

and my database.yml with

```
production:
adapter: mysql2
database: db/production.mysql2
```

before it was set as sqlite3.

I'm newbie, this is my first app that I want to deploy to Amazon AWS so maybe I miss something obvious ! Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it ! I had forgotten to

```
gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
```

The error message in Heroku says to run gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter (without the 2), but with the 2, it works perfectly now !

I hope this post will help others. So, to sum up, here is what you need to do : 
1- Set the "2" in the add-on link in Heroku

```
mysql2://user:pass@mydatabase.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/MyFirstDb
```

2- Add a line to your Gemfile :

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
```

3- Change your database.yml

```
production:
adapter: mysql2
database: db/production.mysql2
```

4- Run

```
gem install activerecord-mysql2
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

And enjoy ! :-)